# Adding version info to jar file name using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, versioning

I'm used to Android Studio and developing Android projects.

In Android Studio I put this in the build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.domain.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "myapp.$versionName.$versionCode")
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def newName = output.outputFile.name
                newName = newName.replace("-release", "")
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

When I build I get myapp.1.0.1.apk, works wonderfully.

Now I am developing a java project .jar using IntelliJ, NOT Android Studio.

How can I accomplish the same thing?  I'm finding sparse information ...

Answer (score 0):

Android does this by adding a task that build the `R.java` file.  As simple as Android makes it look replicating the behavior takes a little effort.  You can create your own gradle task to accomplish the same.  You will need a gradle plugin that creates and extension and a task.  The extension will be used to track values added in the `build.gradle`

Plugin should create extensions and tasks

```
    // create DSL model
    target.extensions.create('buildConfig', BuildConfigModel)
    // create task to generate file
    def buildConfigTask = target.tasks.create('generateBuildConfig', BuildConfigTask)
    target.tasks.findByName('clean').configure {
        delete new File("$project.projectDir/src/main", "generated-sources")
    }
    // this task must always run... it's never `upToDate`
    buildConfigTask.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    // java compiler depends on this task... allows us to reference generated code from
    // human written code
    target.tasks.getByName('compileJava').dependsOn buildConfigTask
```

Here is how you can use your task to add a generated sources file

```
    project.configure(project, { Project configuredProject ->
        // compilerJava task {@link JavaCompile}
        def compileJava = configuredProject.compileJava
        // add the created java file to source path so it gets compiled
        compileJava.source(project.buildConfig.createBuildConfig(project, compileJava))
    })
```

Then our extension would looks something like this

```
package com.jbirdvegas.q41680813;

import com.squareup.javapoet.CodeBlock;
import com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;
import org.gradle.api.GradleException;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile;

import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Handles creating the BuildConfig.java from a module project
 * <p>
 * Warning... Keep this in java, gradle doesn't have the streams api we are using
 */
public class BuildConfigModel {
    /**
     * Final java file output path pattern for {@link String#format(String, Object...) String#format} formatting of
     * the file's path.  Directory structure will be created if needed
     */
    private static final String OUTPUT_PATH_FORMAT = "%s/src/main/generated-sources/%s/%s/BuildConfig.java";

    /**
     * List of DSL supplied {@link BuildValue buildConfig#add}
     */
    private List<BuildValue> mBuildValues = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Required... do not remove
     */
    public BuildConfigModel() {
    }

    /**
     * Create a new field to the project's generated `BuildConfig.java`'s inner class for each type
     *
     * @param clazz Type of value to be written (will be grouped by clazz)
     * @param name  field name to be created
     * @param value value to be assigned to field's name
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})
    public void add(Class clazz, String name, Object value) {
        mBuildValues.add(new BuildValue(clazz, name, value));
    }

    /**
     * Create `BuildConfig.java` and add it to the {@link JavaCompile#source(Object...)}  compileJava#source(Object...)}
     *
     * @param project     module to generate BuildConfig for
     * @param javaCompile project's `compileJava` task
     * @return generated `BuildConfig.java` file
     */
    public File createBuildConfig(Project project, JavaCompile javaCompile) {
        File buildConfigFile = getBuildConfigFile(project);
        createJavaClass(project, buildConfigFile);
        javaCompile.source(buildConfigFile);
        return buildConfigFile;
    }

    /**
     * Destination file for given project's `BuildConfig.java`
     *
     * @param project module to generate BuildConfig for
     * @return File representing the destination of the created `BuildConfig.java`
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public File getBuildConfigFile(Project project) {
        return project.file(String.format(OUTPUT_PATH_FORMAT,
                project.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath(),
                project.getGroup().toString().replaceAll("\\.", "/"),
                project.getName()));
    }

    /**
     * Create `BuildConfig.java` with a few default values and any values supplied
     * to the `buildConfig`'s {@link #add(Class, String, Object) add} method.
     * <p>
     * Default BuildConfig fields will be generated by {@link #getDefaultFields}
     * <p>
     * Fields added via {@link #add(Class, String, Object) add} method will be grouped into inner classes
     * named <pre>{@code Class#getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "s"}</pre>
     *
     * @param project         module to generate BuildConfig for
     * @param buildConfigFile File representing the destination of the BuildConfig.java output
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public void createJavaClass(Project project, File buildConfigFile) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        Collections.sort(mBuildValues);
        // group our configs by their types into a map of groups
        Map<Class, List<BuildValue>> groupedConfigs = mBuildValues.stream()
                // put the values in groups based on the simple name of the class in lowercase
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BuildValue::getValueType));

        // create the fully qualified class that will contain our build settings
        TypeSpec.Builder buildConfigJavaBuilder = TypeSpec.classBuilder("BuildConfig")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                // note for javadoc
                .addJavadoc("$S\n", "DO NOT MODIFY; this class is written automatically by the compiler")
                // replace public constructor with private
                .addMethod(createPrivateConstructor());

        // add any fields that will be in all BuildConfig classes
        buildConfigJavaBuilder.addFields(getDefaultFields(project));

        groupedConfigs.forEach((aClass, buildValues) -> {
            // create the inner class
            String safeInnerClassName = aClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + 's';
            TypeSpec.Builder innerClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(safeInnerClassName)
                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                    // make a constructor that's private since all the members of this class are public static final
                    .addMethod(createPrivateConstructor());
            // for each inner class type create a field
            // each object type gets it's own inner class
            //noinspection SimplifyStreamApiCallChains
            buildValues.stream().forEachOrdered(buildValue -> {
                // create the requested field in the class
                FieldSpec fieldSpec = FieldSpec.builder(buildValue.clazz, buildValue.name)
                        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                        .initializer(CodeBlock.of(getStringFormatter(buildValue.clazz), buildValue.value))
                        .build();
                // add the field to the inner class
                innerClass.addField(fieldSpec);
            });
            // add the inner class to the fully qualified class
            buildConfigJavaBuilder.addType(innerClass.build());
        });

        // determine the package name from project.group + '.' + project.name
        String packageName = project.getGroup() + "." + project.getName();
        // create a java file writer
        JavaFile.Builder builder = JavaFile.builder(packageName, buildConfigJavaBuilder.build());
        // don't import java.lang.* it's redundant
        builder.skipJavaLangImports(true);
        // use four spaces for indent instead of default two spaces
        builder.indent("    ");
        // create the file in memory
        JavaFile javaFile = builder.build();

        // ensure file structure
        if (!buildConfigFile.getParentFile().exists() && !buildConfigFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            throw new GradleException("Failed to create directory structure for " + buildConfigFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        // write BuildConfig.java to location
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(buildConfigFile)) {
            javaFile.writeTo(writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Strings require being treated specially in order to be encapsulated in quotes correctly
     * All other classes are treated as literals... We may want to handle more {@link java.lang.reflect.Type Type}
     *
     * @param clazz Class formatter is needed for
     * @return "$S" if the class is a {@link String} else a literal formatter is returned "$L"
     */
    private String getStringFormatter(Class clazz) {
        switch (clazz.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()) {
            case "string":
                // causes the formatter used to wrap the value in quotes correctly
            case "date":
                // date objects are serialized to a string
                return "$S";
            case "long":
                return "$LL";
            case "double":
                return "$LD";
            case "float":
                return "$LF";
            default:
                // for the reset use literal
                return "$L";
        }
    }

    /**
     * get project added build values
     *
     * @return List of build values added by project's `buildConfig` closure
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public List<BuildValue> collectBuildValues() {
        return mBuildValues;
    }

    /**
     * Make a private constructor for the class. Default is public but our classes only contain
     * <pre>{@code public static final {@link Object}}</pre> so public constructors are redundant
     *
     * @return private constructor method
     */
    private MethodSpec createPrivateConstructor() {
        return MethodSpec.constructorBuilder().addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE).build();
    }

    /**
     * Create default field references
     *
     * @param project module to generate BuildConfig for
     * @return List of fields to write to generated BuildConfig
     */
    private List<FieldSpec> getDefaultFields(Project project) {
        List<FieldSpec> fields = new ArrayList<>();

        // set current version
        fields.add(FieldSpec.builder(String.class, "version")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                .initializer(CodeBlock.of(getStringFormatter(String.class), project.getVersion()))
                .build());
        return fields;
    }

    class BuildValue implements Comparable {
        /**
         * Type of field's value
         */
    /* package */ Class clazz;

        /**
         * Field name
         */
    /* package */ String name;

        /**
         * Field's value Value must be able to be serialized as a string
         */
    /* package */ Object value;

        /* package */ BuildValue(Class clazz, String name, Object value) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        /* package */ Class getValueType() {
            return clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof BuildValue)) return false;

            BuildValue that = (BuildValue) o;

            if (clazz != null ? !clazz.equals(that.clazz) : that.clazz != null) return false;
            if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
            return value != null ? value.equals(that.value) : that.value == null;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = clazz != null ? clazz.hashCode() : 0;
            result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return (name != null && o != null) ? name.compareTo(o.toString()) : -1;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("BuildValue{");
            sb.append("class=").append(clazz.getCanonicalName());
            sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
            sb.append(", value=").append(value);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here by default the plugin will create the `BuildConfig.java` with the default field of `version` but you could add your own values also

```
buildConfig {
    add Boolean, 'myKey', false
}
```

Then at runtime you could get the reference's value with `BuildConfig.value` and for the example above you would also have the field `BuildConfig.myKey` available as a `Boolean` type.

Edit: my example uses groovy for the plugin class and the task class, however the extension, `BuildConfigModel`, is written in java.  All my sources are located in `src/main/groovy`

Comment: Wow.  Thank you for the detailed response.  I won't be able to get to this today, but I'll look at implementing this soon.  It almost seems easier to just manually set the version info myself, but my projects list is growing so in the long run it will be worthwhile to setup an automated solution.